# Is it possible to run xmonad inside unity?

Tags: unity, window-manager

I would like to have xmonad control my window behavior, but still have the ubuntu panel at the top of the screen.  Is this feasible?

Comment: follow this tutorial and let me know is this helpful or not? 
http://www.howtogeek.com/114728/how-to-use-xmonad-a-tiling-window-manager-for-linux/